# Jquery .then not waiting for function to finish

Tags: jquery, deferred

I have a semi complicated chain of promises that need to happen in a certain order. One of the functions that is part of the promise chain is returning the promise before it has been resolved from another function. Example:

```
this.triOverlay = new Image();
this.triOverlayFinal = new Image();

//Start the promise chain for overlay stuff
$.when($.loadImage(this.triOverlay, 'art/small.png'), this.loadAgentImages()).then(function () {
    console.log(">>> ALL DONE!!!! <<<<");
});
```

LoadImage is a simple jQuery function that builds a deferred object and sets it up for image loading and processing:

```
    $.loadImage = function (image, url) {
    // Define a "worker" function that should eventually resolve or reject the deferred object.
    var loadImage = function (deferred) {

        image.onload = loaded;
        image.onerror = errored; // URL returns 404, etc
        image.onabort = errored; // IE may call this if user clicks "Stop"

        image.src = url;

        function loaded() {
            unbindEvents();
            console.log(">>>>> resolved image! URL: ");
            deferred.resolve(image);
        }
        function errored() {
            unbindEvents();
            deferred.reject(image);
        }
        function unbindEvents() {
            // Ensures the event callbacks only get called once.
            image.onload = null;
            image.onerror = null;
            image.onabort = null;
        }
    };
    return $.Deferred(loadImage).promise();
};
```

Where it gets complicated is that in the loadAgentImages I have another set of images that need to be loaded with a clause that needs to happen once those are loaded:

```
CubePan.prototype.loadAgentImages = function () {

    var largePhotoPath = 'someURL'; //Just an example
    var smallPhotoPath = 'someURL2'; //Just an example

    //This cubePan
    var me = this;

    return $.when($.loadImage(this.agent.photo, smallPhotoPath), $.loadImage(this.agent.blurAgentPhoto, largePhotoPath)).then(function () {
        //return deferred.promise();
        console.log(">>>> before start on bluid blur and build TriOverlay <<<<");
        return buildBlur(me);
        //return blur;
    }, function () { console.log(">>>> blur rejected <<<<"); });
};
```

*The original images and call to the loadAgentImages are in the same object. I know i didn't include that above.*

Once the two images have been resolved in the when, the then fires correctly and It calls buildBlur(me):

```
function buildBlur(me) {
    console.log(">>>> buildBlur <<<<");
    var blurCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var blurCTX = blurCanvas.getContext('2d');
    blurCanvas.height = me.agent.blurAgentPhoto.height;
    blurCanvas.width = me.agent.blurAgentPhoto.width;
    blurCTX.drawImage(me.agent.blurAgentPhoto, 0, 0, blurCanvas.width, blurCanvas.height);

    //This function can be found in stackBlur.js
    boxBlurCanvasRGBA(blurCanvas, 0, 0, blurCanvas.width, blurCanvas.height, 20);
    return $.loadImage(me.agent.blurAgentPhotoFinal, blurCanvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0));

};
```

However, BuildBlur does not return the promise once its been resolved its returning it right away. Making the rest of the chain think its resolved, even though the final image (blurAgentPhotoFinal) has not been loaded and resolved yet.

The $.loadImage works in all the instances from above, just not in the instance with buildBlur.

Any ideas why it isnt waiting for the $.loadImage in buildBlur to finish before fully resolving the chain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the Issue. The code was using a very old version of jquery. 1.7. When upgraded to the newest the .Then started working correctly.